# Is there a way to find how many spaces before the first item in awk?

Tags: linux, shell, awk

Here is the input_file:

```
    D    E    F
        H  I   Z
```

What I want to know is the number of white spaces before the first item. Such as a (imaginary) variable `WHITE_SPACES`

```
awk '{
    print WHITE_SPACES $1
}' input_file
```

will return

```
4D
8H
```

Any good tricks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
awk '{print index($0, $1) - 1 $1}' input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this,

```
$ echo '    D    E    F' | awk -v FS="[^[:space:]]" '{str=$0;match(str, FS);fs_str=substr(str, RSTART, RLENGTH);print length($1)fs_str}'
4D
```

I don't know what exactly you want to be the following characters whether it may be the first letter or first word.

```
$ echo '    Dnb    E    F' | awk -v FS="[^[:space:]]" '{str=$0;match(str, FS);fs_str=substr(str, RSTART, RLENGTH);print length($1)fs_str}'
4D
$ echo '    Dnb    E    F' | awk -v FS="[^[:space:]]+" '{str=$0;match(str, FS);fs_str=substr(str, RSTART, RLENGTH);print length($1)fs_str}'
4Dnb
```